# How can I run two ROS2 nodes each in a separate docker container?

Tags: ros, ros2, docker, ardent

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to run two ROS2 nodes, let's say `listener` and `talker` from the `demo_nodes_cpp` package each in a docker container ([osrf/ros2:ardent-basic image](https://hub.docker.com/r/osrf/ros2/)).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280874/how-can-i-run-two-ros2-nodes-each-in-a-separate-docker-container?/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2018-01-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest approach will be to setup the two containers to be on the same network segment. There's lots of ways to do this the docker networking documentation is here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/

You'll likely want to use Docker Compose to automate the multi container launching. I recommend reading the [Docker Compose Documenation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)

Update: @gvdhoorn is right that the new docker behavior is to default to running the containers on the same network.

I verifed I can just run this on one terminal

```
$ docker run -ti --rm osrf/ros2:ardent-full ros2 run examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher publisher_member_function
[INFO] [minimal_publisher]: Publishing: 'Hello, world! 0'
[INFO] [minimal_publisher]: Publishing: 'Hello, world! 1'
[INFO] [minimal_publisher]: Publishing: 'Hello, world! 2'
[INFO] [minimal_publisher]: Publishing: 'Hello, world! 3'
[INFO] [minimal_publisher]: Publishing: 'Hello, world! 4'
[INFO] [minimal_publisher]: Publishing: 'Hello, world! 5'
[INFO] [minimal_publisher]: Publishing: 'Hello, world! 6'
...
```

And in a 2nd terminal:

```
$ docker run -ti --rm osrf/ros2:ardent-full ros2 run examples_rclpy_minimal_subscriber subscriber_member_function
[INFO] [minimal_subscriber]: I heard: "Hello, world! 34"
[INFO] [minimal_subscriber]: I heard: "Hello, world! 35"
[INFO] [minimal_subscriber]: I heard: "Hello, world! 36"
[INFO] [minimal_subscriber]: I heard: "Hello, world! 37"
...
```

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-26**:
Shouldn't this work out-of-the-box? All containers get placed on the same network in a default Docker network configuration.

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-01-27**:
@gvdhoorn @tfoote The network config was not clear to me. @tfoote Thanks for the snippet. BTW: The example can be executed with the image `osrf/ros2-basic` as well.